# How to halt the Ruby debugger (like GDB's CTL-C)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

Is there a way to tell a running "script/server --debugger" to pause execution and open the debugger prompt (other than sticking a "debugger" statement in my code)? Similar to CTL-C in GDB.

I would like to do this, so that I can set a breakpoint in `Base.update_attributes` without having to put "debugger" in my own function (and having to hit "n" every time my function executes).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a direct answer to your question, but you could use Jamis's solution for GDB here: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/25/gdb-wrapper-for-ruby

Comment: Interesting link.

Eventually, I've just handled it by putting a 'debugger' call in the Rails source, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `debugger` earlier on, during app initialization, for example somewhere in boot.rb (as you don't want debugger called each time you call your function) and then add breakpoint from debugger console with `break Base.update_attributes` as [explained here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#breakpoints)